# Serializing Unity Sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to know how to get started about making a sprite (or any other complexe types) serializable  ?

Is each case specific or is there a general approach ?

EDIT:

Let me reiterate my question, I can figure out how to code gamelogic, I've been programming for a couple of months only, but this, this is my first "big" problem that I don't even see where to start looking.

So I'd like to know what it takes to achieve this, what to look for. A starting point.

Comment: [Json](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/3427520)

Comment: Did you actually try doing it? Most types in Unity are already serializeable.

Comment: Yes I tried it, and it says that Sprite is not marked as serializable.

Comment: Is marchalling where I should look, although it seems to be similar ?

Comment: Use json as @zwcloud suggested but why do you need to serialize a sprite? What are you doing?

Comment: Well basically I have a type Item, which retrieves a sprite when I instantiate it in my inventory. When I try to serialize Item it says that the sprite is not marked as serializable.

Comment: Ok. So to actually get a useful answer on this site, you have to post the script that is causing the problem then post the error message as it is. This will help people figure out your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite get what you're trying to do, but if you need a reference to a specific sprite you can do either of these:

1 - Load sprite by name from the [Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html) folder.

```
Sprite sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Items/Sword");
```

2 - Use the [[SerializeField]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) attribute to serialize all your sprites.

```
[SerializeField]
Sprite sprite;
```